# Using htaccess to hide folder in the URL with MAMP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mamp

I am trying to serve pages from a subdirectory while keeping the URL clean. Here's my directory structure:

```
project (document root)
 -- public
 -- app
```

So what I'm trying to do is serve pages from the `public` folder in such a way that the URL will still look like `http://localhost/`.

Here's the `.htaccess` file I'm using in my document root folder. As far as I've read, this should do what I want, but it's not.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
```

When I go to `http://localhost/` in my browser, the URL becomes `http://localhost/public/` in the address bar.

Any ideas?

Comment: that means you get external redirect which is not in the code above.

Comment: Sorry @Deadooshka, I don't understand. How do I make it work like I want it to?

Answer (score 0):

try this, but i'm not sure what you want.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ http://localhost/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Thank you, but I still get the external redirect. I'm sure there's something else at play here, I just can't figure out what it is.

Comment: @AlexandreReiffJanini some scripts has an opion to redirect to the 
correct url, like "enforce canonical URL".